# Find element by TEXT in SeleniumBase

Tags: html, selenium, seleniumbase

I'm using SeleniumBase and I need to click on an element identified like this below:

```
<span class="text">
                Contato PF e PJ
            </span>
```

I need to catch by the text inside (Contato PF e PJ). How can I do this with SeleniumBase?

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
```

self.click(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Contato PF e PJ")]')`

Comment: In that case, I just use self.click('//span[contains(text(), "Contato PF e PJ")]') and worked. I'm using SeleniumBase. Thanks!